# Realm migration must be provided. Field count is less than expected - expected 20 but was 19

Tags: java, android, migration, realm

I have strange behavior with `realm` migrations in my app.

Some users affected by **"io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Field count is less than expected - expected 20 but was 19"**.

The current schema version is 5. The problem has appeared since migration from 3 version to 4 and from 4 to 5.

Before 4 version `SomeObject` and `SomeObject2` contained 19 fields.

```
    // from 3 to 4 version
    if (oldVersion == 3) {
        schema.get("SomeObject")
                .addField("edit_required", boolean.class);

        schema.get("SomeObject2")
                .addField("edit_required", boolean.class);

        oldVersion++;
    }
```

After migration above `SomeObject` and `SomeObject2` should contain 20 fields, but `Realm` says that field count is still 19.

Anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Most likely there is a bug in your logic somewhere. You can use `RealmObjectSchema.getFieldNames()` to get a list of all the field names known by Realm. Then you can probably find out which field is missing.